# Consistent unique value in multiple columns

Tags: cassandra

We are using Cassandra in a project, and, while most of our data fits Cassandra's nature well, we have a few tables that do not. I am investigating if we need a separate system (probably an acid database) to cover this or if we can just use Cassandra.

We want to enforce an unique constraint on 2 columns: publicName and privateName. The artifical primary key for our entity is an UUID. We will also assume an extra column in the datamodel, let's say entityType.

In an SQL db we would do this:

```
entityId UUID PK | publicName TEXT UNIQUE INDEX | privateName TEXT UNIQUE INDEX | entityType INT
```

First instinct is to make three tables:

```
entityId UUID PK | publicName TEXT | privateName TEXT | entityType INT
entityId UUID | publicName TEXT PK | privateName TEXT | entityType INT
entityId UUID | publicName TEXT | privateName TEXT PK | entityType INT
```

The first table is not a problem: if there are some extra entities there, it does not affect the application because there will be no references to it. There will also be no write conflicts because we just generate UUIDs.

However, how can I be sure that, when I have a publicName entry, that entry is always consistent with a privateName entry and UUID entry ; and that when I have a privateName entry, that entry is always consistent with a publicName entry and an UUID entry?

In other words, I want that:

- Entry with some publicName exists **implies** identical entry exists (or will soon exist) in the UUID indexed and the privateName indexed tables
- Entry with
  some privateName exists **implies** identical entry exists (or will soon exist) in the
  UUID index and the publicName indexed tables

My first approach was (using quorum everywhere):

1. Check if publicName or privateName taken, and fail if taken
2. Insert into the 3 tables in a logged batch

This would, I believe, work, if it wasn't for timestamp ties. If there is a tie between 2 batches, I will get some cells from the first batch, and some from the other (cassandra uses the lexically greater value on a cell value to resolve timestamp tie conflicts if I believe my research on the subject).
This could also possible acknowledge an entity creation that would later be overwritten, but that is not really a problem in the case of our system.

Is it possible, with cassandra, to achieve consistency in this scenario even when timestamps tie?
Or should I start installing a whole new component in our system just for this?

Edit: using a batch doesn't work at all, because another entity may use the same publicName, or the same privateName, and not both.

Comment: Did you look at [lightweight transactions](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0)?

You could have something like
`UPDATE table 
SET entityType = 11
WHERE entityId = xxx
IF publicName = a AND privateName = b`

Comment: I know about LWT and used it successfuly for single table consistency. But in this case, we have more than one table. I want both byPublicName and byPrivateName to be consistent with each other. LWT cannot, AFAIK, span multiple partitions, right?